# Understanding GitHub work flow; what to do after cloning from github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, workflow

I am working with RoR, and have recently cloned a project via GitHub.  I have a specific RVM gemset for this project, but nothing inside of it.  I am not sure if I should create a new branch and then run `bundle install`, or vice versa.  My concern is I do not want to work on the master branch, but I know I need to set up everything first run `bundle install`.

What is the right method to get started on this project, with out breaking the master?

Comment: Define "break"; it ain't gonna run if you don't install your gems. And you're not breaking the *remote* master, but *yours*. *Code* changes should generally be done on branches, but you can't do much of anything until you install your gems.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks, I used the term "break" out of inexperience.  But your explanation helped clear things up.  So based on that, now that I have cloned the project, the first step is to run bundle install, then create a new branch to make code changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub is just a hosting for git repositories. Well, writing *just* is not giving it proper justice.

However you should learn how truly `git` works. I heartily recommend reading free [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book).

In short:

1. git is distributed
2. you're working only on local working copy
3. if you don't tell git *specifically* you want a file to be tracked - it won't (surprise, surprise!).

So running `bundle install` **will not modify** what is tracked by git and - specifically - won't affect remote `master`. It won't modify **your master** until you modify some files being already tracked. I think `bundle install` does not. And even then to modify remote `master` you need to `commit` and `push` changes.

You can work on your `master`. It's safe.

Answer (score 1):

If its someone else's project, or an open-source project, you should Fork the project on Github.  Then clone the fork.  This will allow you to work on the project, commit your changes locally and push them back to the forked repository.

If it is your own project, and you do indeed want to work in a branch, then clone the repo and make a branch `git checkout -b my_branchname`.  You will then work in the branch, check your code into the branch.  Eventually you will want to merge this branch into the master branch.  To do this you can merge locally:

```
git checkout master
git merge my_branchname
```

Or, you can create a pull request on Github and then merge the branch into master through the Github web UI.

The `bundle` command, used in conjunction with RVM will just install gems locally, most likely in your home directory (`~/.rvm`).  Gems are not packaged with the rest of the code, so you don't need to fear messing up the master repo.